# Chromium doesn't honour --disable-http2

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, http2

I know that all instances need to be closed before using this flag.

Chrome honours `--disable-http2` as expected, I can visit https://nghttp2.org/ and I only see HTTP/1 traffic.

Chromium doesn't honour this though.  I run Chromium with `chrome.exe --disable-http2` and navigate to https://nghttp2.org/, but traffic is still being recorded as HTTP/2 in the network tab.

Comment: It could be because of field trials. Try this when launching Chromium: `chrome.exe --force-fieldtrials --disable-http2`